# Notation for "first $x$ where $f(x)$ greater than $t$"?

Tags: notation

What is the preferred notation for expressing the first $x$ where $f(x)$ is greater than a threshold $t$.   This is similar to $\arg\max$ notation but instead of max, I want the first $x$ where $f(x)$ is greater than $t$.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's a standard notation for this concept specifically, but one could express it as
$$\inf f^{-1}((t,\infty)).$$
Alternately, as Henning points out below, we could write
$$\min\{x\mid f(x)>t\},$$
which is indeed significantly clearer.

Note that using $\inf$ instead of $\min$ guarantees the quantity exists, but we may not actually have $f(a)>t$ where $a=\inf\{x\mid f(x)>t\}$.

Comment: The open interval notation inside parentheses are confusing, I think. It would be worth the extra clarity to write it out explicitly as $\min\{x\mid f(x)>t\}$ -- which is not even that much longer.

Comment: That's a much better suggestion - I've CW'ed the post and added it.

Comment: If interval notation is to be used, a better (= more readable) version is $\inf f^{-1}[(t,\to)]$ (or $\inf f^{-1}[(t,\infty)]$, though I prefer the arrow form). If $R$ is a binary relation and $S$ is a subset of its domain, I much prefer $R[S]$ to $R(S)$ for $\{y:\exists x\in S(x R y)\}$.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you Zev and Henning!

Comment: This comes up all the time in probability (usually $f$ is a stochastic process) and is almost universally denoted by $\inf\{x : f(x) > t\}$ (or $\min$ if appropriate).  So +1 for @HenningMakholm.

Comment: These are not so much *notations* as formulas for what's to be denoted.

Answer (score 2):

My prefered notation for the first $x$ where $f(x)$ greater than $t$ is “the first x where f(x) greater than t”.